# Copying data from many workbooks to a summary workbook with Excel-VBA. Run time errors

Tags: vba, excel

I have files in a folder and I want to copy data from these files and paste them into another Master workbook sheet.

I keep getting a runtime `error ‘1004’`: Sorry we couldn’t find C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER`, It is possible it was moved, renamed or deleted.

The error is highlighted on this line of code: `Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName`

I have seen other questions similar to this on the web, I have tried making various changes. But still without success. Please advise.

- Dir for source files: `C:\Users\ jjordan \Desktop\Test Dir\GA Test\`
- Dir for Master file:   `C:\Users\ jjordan \Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\`
- Source filenames differ, but all end in `"*.xlsx."`
- Master filename: `" MASTER – Data List - 2016.xlsm "` ‘macro file
- Source worksheet name = `"Supplier_Comments"`
- Master worksheet name = `"Sheet5"`

  ```
  Option Explicit

   Sub GetDataFromMaster()

        Dim MyPath As String
        Dim SumPath As String
        Dim MyName As String
        Dim SumName As String
        Dim MyTemplate As String
        Dim SumTemplate As String
        Dim myWS As Worksheet
        Dim sumWS As Worksheet

       'Define folders and filenames
        MyPath = "C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\GA Test\"
        SumPath = "C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\MASTER\"

        MyTemplate = "*.xlsx"  'Set the template.
       SumTemplate = "MASTER – Data List - 2016.xlsm"

       'Open the template file and get the Worksheet to put the data into
       SumName = Dir(SumPath & SumTemplate)
       Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName
       Set sumWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")

       'Open each source file, copying the data from each into the template file
       MyName = Dir(MyPath & MyTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file

       Do While MyName <> ""

      'Open the source file and get the worksheet with the data we want.
       Workbooks.Open MyPath & MyName
       Set myWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suppliers_Comment")
      'Copy the data from the source and paste at the end of sheet 5
       myWS.Range("A2:N100").Copy
       sumWS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial         Paste:=xlPasteValues
       'Close the current sourcefile and get the next
       Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False        'close
       MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
       Loop
      'Now all sourcefiles are copied into the Template file. Close and save it
       Workbooks(SumName).Close SaveChanges:=True

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: I have seen many similar questions on this site, and i edited their question to format their code to be readable, but still there are more and more new apearing, please format your code, then maybe you get your advice.

Comment: By that error, are you sure your paths are correct?

Comment: @Lubos, yes there are similar questions. But I have tried debug this problem in the code. But no luck! The code format is better now. No?

Comment: @ Lubos, Yes.I have copied the Location under properties on the file.

Comment: Try defining the desktop path using `MyPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop") & "\Test Dir\GA Test\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a template for what you'd like done. NOTE that forward slashes can cause run time error b/c vba handles them in an annoying way.

```
 Sub DougsLoop()
     Dim wbk As Workbook
     Dim Filename As String
     Dim path As String
     Dim rCell As Range
     Dim rRng As Range
     Dim wsO As Worksheet
     Dim StartTime As Double
     Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
     Dim sheet As Worksheet

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'these three statements help performance by disabling the self titled in each, remeber to re-enable at end of code
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

     StartTime = Timer 'Starts timer to see how long code takes to execute. I like having this in macors that loop through files

     path = "C:\Users\jjordan\Desktop\Test Dir\GA Test" & "\" 'pay attention to this line of code********
     Filename = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
     Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")

     Do While Len(Filename) > 0 'this tells the code to stop when there are no more files in the destination folder
         DoEvents
         Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(path & Filename, True, True)
             For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                Set rRng = sheet.Range("a2:n100")
                For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
                    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell
                Next rCell
             Next
         wbk.Close False
         Filename = Dir
     Loop

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
     MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
 End Sub
```

alter to this to your needs and you'll find it works perfectly :)

EDIT: Also in your code you make use of COPY & PASTE a lot. Try avoid doing this in the future. Try doing something:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value = OtherWork.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Value
```

This is more efficient and wont bog down your code as much.

here is some offset logic

```
 wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value =
 wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = 
 wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value =
```

notice the Offset(x,y) value? Essentially x is down and y is right. this is of course referencing the original position. So to get a value to go in the same row but three columns over you would use "Offset(0,3)" etc etc

Ill let you alter your code to do this. :)

I guess actually trying to piece it together was a struggle? Here this version assumes the macro is in the master workbook(and that youre running it form the master). If you want to change go ahead, but this is as far as I go. At some point, you'll have to experiment on your own.

Comment: Thanks Doug, but my I am a beginner with VBA and hence I am more confused. Especially with the Do While Loop where you mention " Some Code".

Comment: "some code" means "fill in this space with what you need the code to do"

Comment: @JamesJordan I have edited it with more comments so that it is more clear for you what some parts do

Comment: Thanks Doug. But I am still no closer to the solution.

Comment: @JamesJordan try this

Comment: @JamesJordan  I removed an End If that was not needed. You can see edited code

Comment: @ Doug. We have taken a BIG step forward. The macro ran without any error and it was pretty neat seeing that the macro took 2.08secs! Thanks!! But, the data from the template file pasted everything into one column. All the data on the template sheet was in 4 columns. Actually, there are many files (templates) that need to be pasted on different master workbook on different sheets (sheet 5, sheet 7, sheet 13 etc.). How can I copy and paste the exact columns and rows for each template sheet?

Comment: Basically, I need to copy and paste Xrows & Ycolumns from a template sheet into Xrows & Ycolumns on "different" sheets within the Master Workbook.

Comment: Should I post this question as Answered? Then post a new question about  pasting the copy and pasting the data into different locations etc?

Comment: i can fix the offset issue. hold please

Comment: @JamesJordan I have included some offset logic for you to use to get the desired results. And yes please mark as answered when you figure it out.

Comment: @ Doug. Thanks a lot. I will keep this as answered and post another question to get the location copy and paste of data right. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I will hold... I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JamesJordan, I have already included the offset logic. Please review code

Comment: Thanks Doug. I will give it a try... You have been very helpful.