# Running all files in a folder through a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies if I over-word my dilemma. I want to make sure I'm crystal clear.

I have a workbook with a macro I wrote that analyzes and consolidates a large amount of data. The workbook itself has two worksheets: "Data Entry" and "Output". Data entry has the macro buttons within the first row, so the data starts at Cell "A2". Output is where the end data is placed, starting at Cell "A1".

What I would like to do is build upon the macro to be used in processing multiple files of raw data in a single process. Bear in mind none of the raw data files will be opened. Only the one running this macro. I would like to have the workbook itself:

1. Pull the worksheet data from all files in a folder, one at a time. There will be a variable amount of files in this folder. (To clarify, each raw data file placed into this folder will be a single worksheet with the data starting at Cell "A1", and the name of said files will vary)
2. Pull said data from a file and import it into "Data Entry" at Cell "A2"
3. Run my code, process the data and dump it into the worksheet "Output". (It's worth noting that "Data Entry" is 30 columns wide with variable row length, and output is variable in column and row length)
4. Take what is within the worksheet "Output", return it to the file it grabbed the raw data from, but in a new worksheet on the raw data workbook.
5. Loop this process until all raw data files have been run through the the workbook and have an "Output" worksheet.

Comment: You might have over-worded your dilemma, but you don't seem to have actually asked a question..? If you've written some code and it doesn't do what you'd expect, or throws an error, let us see it and we'll do our best to help.

Comment: @CLR Sorry that I forgot to add the question at the end. How can I effectively grab every workbook in a folder to loop my macro through each one?

Comment: It's been done a million times a million different ways. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298439 for an example and then peruse the 'Related' sections for other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will loop through a folder and add all filenames into an array if they have an .xlsm extension, this could be changed for whatever file you are looking for, then you can loop through the array to open each file and do whatever you need:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim Arr() As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FolderPath = "C:\Users\YOU\Documents"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
i = 0
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Files
'Debug.Print objSubFolder.Name
    If Right(objSubFolder.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then 'if file extension is = xlsm then add to array
        ReDim Preserve Arr(i + 1)
        Arr(i) = objSubFolder.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

For x = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
'Go through each file in your array
Next x

End Sub
```